# prevent click event on element for 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code below. When I click on the `.click` div, it appends a text into `.append` div.

Now what I want is when I click the `.click` div first time the text should be appended to `.append` div, but second click should be active after 2 second. Means no matter how many times I clicks I in `.click` div between 0 to 2 second, the event should be triggered once.

I have tried `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()` but not working.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.click', function(event) {
  $('.append').append('<span>append</span>');
  setTimeout(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }, 2000);
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">click</div>
<div class="append"></div>
```

Comment: if your are requesting something from server side and meanwhile dont want to process again then use CallBack feature of ajax rather then wait for 2 second, because requirement will be change time by time. Clear your requirement and we will provide your proper solution.

Comment: @bharatpatel I am just using it for adding a text in a static file. No server

Comment: So many ways to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Event delegation use it to take advantage, *remove* the selector class i.e. `click` in the event handler and then *add* it after the interval.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.click', function(event) {
  $('.append').append('<span>append</span>');
  var self = $(this);
  self.removeClass('click'); //Remove the class
  setTimeout(function(elem) {
    elem.addClass('click'); //Add the class
  }, 2000, self);
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">click</div>
<div class="append"></div>
```

Comment: why you have used `self` in the second last line?

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt, passing it inner method. Overthinking you can directly use self also

Comment: yeah directly using self working fine. but when I am directly using `$(this)` instead of self, its not working. can you explain why?

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt because this don't refer s to current Element

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding a click variable and an if statement.

On the first click it checks the variable and runs the function, but also updates the variable. The variable is then reset after 2 seconds to re-activate the function.

```js
var clickActive = 1;

$(document).on('click', '.click', function(event) {
  if (clickActive) {
    $('.append').append('<span>append</span>');
    clickActive = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
      clickActive = 1;
    }, 2000);
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">click</div>
<div class="append"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery [**`.one()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to set the handler, and then after 2 sec, set it again using `.one()`.

The `.one()` method adds a one time event handler, that is removed as soon as the event is invoked.

```js
function eventHandler(event) {
  $('.append').append('<span>append</span>');
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(document).one('click', '.click', eventHandler);
  }, 2000);
}

$(document).one('click', '.click', eventHandler);
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">click</div>
<div class="append"></div>
```

Comment: what if I have to pass a parameter in the `eventHandler()` function like `eventHandler(para1)`. I tried but its giving error _**f.apply is not a function**_

Comment: Use the `event.data` -> $(document).one('click', '.click', para1, eventHandler);`, and then `eventHandler(e) { // e.data is para1 }` or just use `para1` in the callback itself.

Answer (score 1):

Althought using setTimeout is an option I personally prefer to avoid setting timers when possible and track time from the last click with a variable:

```
var lastClickTime = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.click', function(event) {
  var thisClickTime = new Date().getTime();
  if (thisClickTime - lastClickTime > 2000) {
    $('.append').append('<span>append</span>');
    lastClickTime = thisClickTime;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep trace with a variable :

```js
var clicked = false;

$(document).on('click', '.click', function(event) {
  if(!clicked){
    clicked = true;
    $('.append').append('<span>append</span>');
    setTimeout(function() {
      clicked = false;
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">click</div>
<div class="append"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a "flag" variable.

```js
var enabled = true;

$(document).on('click', '.click', function(event) {
  if (!enabled) return;

  $('.append').append('<span>append</span>');
  enabled = false;

  setTimeout(function() {
    enabled = true;
  }, 2000);
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click">click</div>
<div class="append"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
var isClickActive = true;
$(document).on('click', '.click', function(event) {
  if(isClickActive){
     appendDiv();
     isClickActive = false;
  } else {
     $(".click").css({'pointer-events':'none'});
     setTimeout(function(){
        $(".click").css({'pointer-events':'auto'});
        appendDiv();
     },2000);
  }
})
function appendDiv(){
   $('.append').append('<span>append</span>');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi you may want to do something like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.click', function(event) {
 var divState = false;
 if(divState ){ setTimeout(function() {
       $('.append').append('<span>append</span>'); 
   divState=false; },2000);
   } else{ 
     $('.append').append('<span>append</span>');divState= true;
  }
})
```

**or**

```
$(document).on('click', '.click', function(event) {
 var divState = false;
 divState ? function(){setTimeout(function() {
       $('.append').append('<span>append</span>'); 
   divState = false },2000);} : function(){ 
   $('.append').append('<span>append</span>'); divState = true;};
})
```

Which ever works best for you